# error in trigger creation also how to optimise it

Tags: mysql, triggers

Please tell me whats wrong with the code. Not able to fine the bug

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_status  BEFORE Update ON listing_basic_new_updated 
FOR EACH ROW
 if new.processing_status is not null 
    then begin
    SET new.rep_status = New.processing_status;
    end; 
  elseif new.televeri_status is not null 
    then begin
    SET new.rep_status = New.televeri_status;
    end; 
  elseif new.verification_status is not null 
    then begin
    SET new.rep_status = New.verification_status;
    end;
end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: shows error in the last line.

Comment: Hint: if you're given an error message, even if you don't understand it, including it in your question can greatly assist others in helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a `BEGIN` that would match up to your `END` at the end:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_status  BEFORE Update ON listing_basic_new_updated 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if new.processing_status is not null 
    then begin
    SET new.rep_status = New.processing_status;
    end; 
  elseif new.televeri_status is not null 
    then begin
    SET new.rep_status = New.televeri_status;
    end; 
  elseif new.verification_status is not null 
    then begin
    SET new.rep_status = New.verification_status;
    end;
end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I think you might be able to replace all of it with

```
SET new.rep_status = COALESCE(new.processing_status, new.televeri_status,
                           new.verification_status, new.rep_status);
```

[`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce): "Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values."

Comment: your right! It works.. can i also ask you how i can optimise that code?

Comment: Added a suggestion at the bottom of my answer - I think it's equivalent.